# TicTacToe minimax AI in Javascript

Tags: javascript, recursion, tic-tac-toe

I'm having trouble implementing this TicTacToe AI that [I found here](http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax). I'm relatively new to javascript so I'm sure I'm doing something wrong with variable scoping.

The code wont run in the snippet but [heres my codepen](http://codepen.io/kennethjmyers/pen/YqBOEr?editors=0110)

```js
choices = {
  0: '#ul',
  1: '#um',
  2: '#ur',
  3: '#ml',
  4: '#mm',
  5: '#mr',
  6: '#ll',
  7: '#lm',
  8: '#lr'
}

function getGrid() {
  var divs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    divs.push($(choices[i]).html())
  }
  return divs
}

function getGame() {
  var divs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    divs.push([$(choices[i]).html(), i])
  }
  return divs
}

function convertGameToGrid(game) {
  var divs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
    divs.push(game[i][0])
  }
  return divs
}

function checkGrid(divs) {
  var options = [
    [divs[0], divs[1], divs[2]],
    [divs[3], divs[4], divs[5]],
    [divs[6], divs[7], divs[8]],
    [divs[0], divs[3], divs[6]],
    [divs[1], divs[4], divs[7]],
    [divs[2], divs[5], divs[8]],
    [divs[0], divs[4], divs[8]],
    [divs[2], divs[4], divs[6]]
  ]

  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    if (options[i][0] == 'X' && options[i][1] == 'X' && options[i][2] == 'X') {
      return 'X'
    } else if (options[i][0] == 'O' && options[i][1] == 'O' && options[i][2] == 'O') {
      return 'O'
    }
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    if (divs[i] == '') {
      return false //still moves
    }
  }
  return 'Tie' //no winner and no moves
}

var player = 'O'
var ai = 'X'

$(document).ready(function() {

  function playerTurn(i) {
    return function() {
      var g = getGrid()
      var cG = checkGrid(g)
      if (!cG) {
        if ($(choices[i]).html() == '') {
          $(choices[i]).html(player)
          var g = getGrid()
          var cG = checkGrid(g)
          if (cG == player) {
            console.log('You win')
          } else if (cG == 'Tie') {
            console.log('Tie')
          } else {
            aiTurn()
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
    $(choices[i]).on('click', playerTurn(i));
  }

  function score(g, depth) {
    var cG = checkGrid(g)
    console.log(cG, g)
    if (cG == ai) {
      return 10 - depth
    } else if (cG == player) {
      return depth - 10
    } else {
      return 0
    }
  }

  function minimax(game, depth) {
    var g = convertGameToGrid(game)
    if (checkGrid(g)) {
      return score(g, depth)
    }
    depth += 1
    var scores = []
    var moves = []

    var availMoves = getAvailMoves(game)
    console.log('moves', availMoves)
    for (var i = 0; i < availMoves.length; i++) {
      var possibleGame = game
      if (depth % 2 == 0) {
        possibleGame[availMoves[i]][0] = ai
      } else {
        possibleGame[availMoves[i]][0] = player
      }
      var m = minimax(possibleGame, depth)
      scores.push(m)
      console.log('mm: ', depth, i, scores)
      moves.push(availMoves[i])
    }

    //even depths are ai, odd are player
    if (depth % 2 == 0) {
      var max_score_index = 0
      var max_score = -100000000
      for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] > max_score) {
          max_score_index = i
          max_score = scores[i]
        }
      }
      if (depth == 0) { //we need the best move
        return moves[max_score_index]
      } else { //otherwise this function needs scores
        return scores[max_score_index]
      }
    } else {
      var min_score_index = 0
      var min_score = 100000000
      for (var i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        if (scores[i] < min_score) {
          min_score_index = i
          min_score = scores[i]
        }
      }
      return scores[max_score_index]
    }
  }

  function getAvailMoves(game) {
    var moves = []
    for (var i = 0; i < game.length; i++) {
      if (game[i][0] == '') {
        moves.push(game[i][1])
      }
    }
    return moves
  }

  function aiTurn() {
    //Dumb ai
    // c = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)
    // while ($(choices[c]).html()) {
    //   c = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)
    // }

    //new strategy taken from http://neverstopbuilding.com/minimax
    console.log('ai')
    var c;
    game = getGame()
    c = minimax(game, -1)

    $(choices[c]).html('X')
    var g = getGrid()
    var cG = checkGrid(g)
    if (cG == ai) {
      console.log('You lose')
    } else if (cG == 'Tie') {
      console.log('Tie')
    }
  }


})
```

```css
#ttt-box {
  position: relative;
  height: 304px;
  width: 304px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border: solid #000 4px;
  border-radius: 20%;
}
#l1,
#l2,
#l3,
#l4 {
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
}
#l1 {
  left: 99px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 296px;
}
#l2 {
  left: 199px;
  width: 3px;
  height: 296px;
}
#l3 {
  top: 99px;
  width: 296px;
  height: 3px;
}
#l4 {
  top: 199px;
  width: 296px;
  height: 3px;
}
#ul,
#um,
#ur,
#ml,
#mm,
#mr,
#ll,
#lm,
#lr {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  width: 99px;
  height: 99px;
  font-size: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
#ul {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
#um {
  top: 0;
  left: 101px;
}
#ur {
  top: 0;
  left: 201px;
}
#ml {
  top: 101px;
  left: 0;
}
#mm {
  top: 101px;
  left: 101px;
}
#mr {
  top: 101px;
  left: 201px;
}
#ll {
  top: 201px;
  left: 0;
}
#lm {
  top: 201px;
  left: 101px;
}
#lr {
  top: 201px;
  left: 201px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="content">
      <div id="ttt-box">
        <div id="l1"></div>
        <div id="l2"></div>
        <div id="l3"></div>
        <div id="l4"></div>

        <div id="boxes">
          <div id="ul"></div>
          <div id="um"></div>
          <div id="ur"></div>
          <div id="ml"></div>
          <div id="mm"></div>
          <div id="mr"></div>
          <div id="ll"></div>
          <div id="lm"></div>
          <div id="lr"></div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

The code in particular that I think is breaking is the section below. After the first player's move, I think the console.log should print out 8! times because of all the different paths that should be taken, instead it only prints 8 times as if it went down a single path.

`var availMoves = getAvailMoves(game)
    console.log('moves',availMoves)
    for (var i=0;i<availMoves.length;i++) {
      var possibleGame = game
      if (depth%2==0) {
        possibleGame[availMoves[i]][0] = ai
      } else {
        possibleGame[availMoves[i]][0] = player
      }
      var m = minimax(possibleGame,depth)
      scores.push(m)
      console.log('mm: ', depth,i, scores)
      moves.push(availMoves[i])
    }`

Edit: What I'm noticing is that sometimes the minimax recursion is returning undefined. I've tried finding why that is (see my codepen) but I've been unsuccessful.

Edit2: It appears to be returning undefined because it is completely skipping these recursions. I still can't find a way to fix this though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First a suggestion, since you're just getting started: learn how to use the debugger. It will be invaluable in cases like these and most modern browsers have them built in.

Regarding your issue, I haven't traced through all your code but I did notice one thing that could be causing the problem in your `minmax` function. Towards the bottom of that function you have this code:

```
//even depths are ai, odd are player
if (depth % 2 == 0) {
    var max_score_index = 0
    // snip...
} else {
    var min_score_index = 0
    // snip...
    return scores[max_score_index]
}
```

Note that you are declaring and assigning `max_score_index` in the `if` block, but also using it in the `else` block (without assigning it). That will cause it to return undefined from the `else` block.

Comment: Thanks! That was definitely an issue. It got rid of my 'undefined' problem but its still not working properly, I'll try to figure out more later. By the debugger, is there something better built in than just going through the console? My code isn't throwing errors so there isn't anything for me to trace in the console but if you have more advice about the best way to debug JS I'll gladly take it

Comment: You get to the debugger much like you get to the console, through the developer tools. In IE and FireFox developer tools, select the "Debugger" tab. In Chrome developer tools, select the "Sources" tab. Once there, you can set breakpoints, examine variable values, and step through your code. There's nothing like seeing the code in action to solve problems.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Jack, I got everything working, my other problem ended up being a deep copy error and I didn't need to use the debugger but I'll definitely be using it from now